# Change div id attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs. When I click on a button it moves to another div

Here is it looks like

I realize it like this

[image]

```
 var counter = 0;
$('.click2').on('click', function () {
    counter++;
    if (counter > 10) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
        $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();

    }
});
```

But I have one problem I need to change Id of elements when it moves

I know that is realizing like this

```
 $(this).attr('id', '.title_left');
```

But I can have 1-10 divs in left column and need to name it `.title_left1`. Next will be `title_left2` and ++

How I can code it?

Comment: I see that you use a counter, why don't you make use of that to update the class? But why would you want to update the class?

Comment: Why would you need to change the `id`? What are you using the `id` attribute for?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, he says two different things in his code. First `$(this).attr('id', '.title_left');` then he says he wants `classes` like `.title_left1`. His question is unclear.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you don't change `id` attributes dynamically. They are designed to be immutable. If you need to amend content on the fly, use classes

Comment: Are you want to put '.' in you div's ID attribute

Comment: Dudes sorry for question. I think I need to change logic for View and not move divs. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append counter to the id attribute:

```
$(this).attr('id', '.title_left' + counter);
```

Comment: `id` attribute, the second argument seems more like a `class` selector to me.

Comment: @lonut, yes I know, but that is the name the OP specified... I wouldn't use commas in id property for sure..